# Is there an event in the request pipeline where both Request and Response are available and populated?

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule, pipeline

I need to bind to an event in the request pipeline where both the Request and Response are populated.  The Request is simple, but I need the StatusCode off the Response object.  At what point in the pipeline is the Response populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473(VS.85).aspx) under the "The request is processed by the HttpApplication pipeline" section.  The "[EndRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest(VS.85).aspx)" event should have what you need.

Comment: It's populated, but it doesn't appear to be accurate.  It's returning 200, even when something isn't found.

Comment: Do you have a custom 404 page?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's something to do with my server set-up -- its rewriting the URL or something.